# Machine Learning Library Specialized for documents

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, document-classification

I am doing a project and I need to find out a machine learning library written in java specialized for document classification. Can anyone please give me some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two famous Java libraries

Stanford core NLP - http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml

GATE - http://osdir.com/ml/ai.gate.general/2007-05/msg00003.html, https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch19.html#chap:ml

Comment: I would also add OpenNLP DocumentCategorizer. Many people use it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the kind of ML you are looking for.

There is the linguistic part of the problem (parsing documents, extracting entities, etc.) which can significantly improve the result, and the ML algorithms part.
For the latter look at [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/algorithms.html), for example - it also has examples of document classifications coming with it. Especially if you plan to deal with a lot of data. Stanford classifier is also a good choice to start with.

Comment: It all depends on the language and the level of analysis you need. For many classifications tasks a simple tokenizer+stemmer would be sufficient (Lucene does that, or you can tokenize yourself and use Snowball stemmer). For more advanced level of analysis you can use the already mentioned Stanford parser or GATE, or Apache OpenNLP. An even heavier approach may require an entire pipeline, like UIMA or GATE.

Answer (score 0):

Both machine learning frameworks MALLET (http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/classification.php) and Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) can do document classification. They are both easy to get started with compared to say Mahout or Spark.